# new project not created in android studio

Tags: android, ide, gradle, android-studio

I've just downloaded android studio 0.3.2 on windows. I have 64bit versions of gre7 and jdk1.7.0 installed on my pc.

I have also made sure I have gradle and it is also 64bit. but still I can't create a new project with android studio. (note: at the same time everything is ok with intellij13)

I get the following error message when I try to create a new project.

> Cause: error in opening zip file
>
> Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

How do you think I can resolve this issue?

-- I even don't know where on earth is this log file!!

Comment: There should be an Android Studio update available; I think it's up to 0.4.0 on the dev channel.

Comment: The option is not named correctly, Earlier it was `Show log` but now it is `Show Log in Explore` under Help menu(Not sure what is it in 0.3.2). As suggested by Scott you should update your Android Studio to 0.4.0 at-least, things are lot improved in current releases.

Comment: I get to developer.andoird.com -> Get SDK -> Android Studio - download. 
I found 0.4.0 version mirros but I wonder if this version is yet stable or not? if it is why the links on the most obvious page for downloading android studio is not updated?!!

Comment: Its a stable release and far better than 0.3.2, which you have. Yo can go ahead to update without any worry.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Start Android Studio, close any open project.

```
On the right side, click on Configure -> Settings.

On the left side, in Compiler->Gradle set VM Options to "-Xmx512m" (without quotes)
On the left side, in Gradle set VM Options to "-Xmx512m" (without quotes)
```

Comment: I have, this is a duplicate answer of another question. I have searched stackoverflow before posting this question.